Cannot spin up postgres with docker-compose AND run knex migrations in one liner inside package.json
I have started working on a project where they have a docker compose file used to spin up a local postgres instance for local dev purposes, and they are using knex.js for migrations.
Inside the package.json scripts, there is the line:
"setupDb": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d --renew-anon-volumes && knex migrate:latest",
When I run npm run setupDb, the docker image spins up, but when it gets to running the migrations, it throws the following error:
Connection terminated unexpectedly Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/tom/Documents/dhub-backend/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:73) at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:625:28) at Connection.emit (node:events:511:28) at Connection.emit (node:domain:489:12) at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/tom/Documents/dhub-backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:63:12) at Socket.emit (node:events:511:28) at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12) at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:334:12)
Although, if I manually run those two commands separately in my terminal (i.e. first run docker-compose up, then run npx knex migrate:latest), it works fine.
I'm not sure if it's just a timing thing, i.e. postgres isn't ready to accept connections when it gets to running the migrations, or if it's some context related thing.
I haven't heard anyone else reporting on this problem, despite there being other devs who've worked on this project for a while. I believe they're all running windows, while I'm running Ubuntu, so I'm also not sure if that has anything to do with it.
Any clues or advice would be appreciated. Running the commands separately works fine and I kinda hate packaging long scripts into package.json files like this. But it would be good to understand what's happening.
